# Solution for $\frac{dx}{dt} = 1+x^{1/3}; \, x(0)=c$ where $1+x^{1/3}$ is not Lipschitz's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to ask that if $f$ is not Lipschitz's and also $f(x)$ is not positive for all $x$ then how can we prove or disprove the uniqueness of solution?

Particularly I am interested to check the uniqueness of the solution of below IVP

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = 1+x^{1/3}; \quad x(0)=c$$
and here $1+x^{1/3}$ is not Lipschitz's.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the differential equation $$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = 1+x^{1/3}; \quad x(0)=c$$  We do not have the Lipschitz's condition to guarantee the uniqueness.

Unfortunately there is no theorem to determine the existence of multiple solutions either.

Note that the  differential equation is separable so we can solve it and get the general solution.

We also have the constant solution of $$x(t) =-1$$ if $$x(0)= c=-1.$$

Thus the uniqueness depends on the initial condition.